# Unable to find css and html file with module.module.id angular 2

Tags: angular

I find this very odd but there has to be something I am doing wrong:

@Component({

```
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-library',
    templateUrl: 'mainPage.html',
    styleUrls: ['bootstrap.css']
})
```

both are not able to be found. I have tried relative path too and that still did not work:

[image: layout]

I have tied to move the css and js files outside of the `app dir` but still same result.

full dir path:

[image: full path]

Comment: you should keep the template file and style sheets in the same folder where your component file is. Though it is not necessary but a recommended [style guide](https://angular.io/styleguide#!#04-06) in angular2.

Comment: @HirenParekh I have tried every path I could think of. I would like to keep some convention and use bootstrap.css files instead of having to retype css for each component.

However now I put the html page, css script and component under the same file and it still will not find my css file.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up taking out `moduleId: module.id,`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-library',
    templateUrl: 'app/library/homePage/mainPage.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/css/bootstrap.css'],
})
```